# How to handle error thrown by module in perl

Tags: oracle, perl, error-handling

I am using the module `DBD::Oracle` in perl to insert xml contents into oracle 11 g instance. While inserting some of the documents in my sample set the script fails as the module returns `Unsupported named object type for bind parameter`. I would like to handle this error and make the loop iteration to go on.

following is my code,

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use DBD::Oracle qw(:ora_session_modes);
use DBD::Oracle qw(:ora_types);

die("USAGE: $0 <input_directory>") unless ($#ARGV == 0);
my $directory=$ARGV[0];

my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:Oraclle:dbname',"username", "pass");
my $SQL;



opendir(IMD, $directory) || die ("Cannot open directory");
my @listOfFiles= readdir(IMD);
closedir(IMD);

my $xmltype_string;
my $xml;
my $i = 1; 
foreach my $file(@listOfFiles)
{
    unless($file eq '.' or $file eq '..')
    {
        print "inserting File no. $i \t $file .... \n";

        {
                local $/=undef;
                open (FILE , "<" , "$directory/$file" );
                $xml=<FILE>;
                close (FILE);
        }
        $SQL="insert into sampleTable values ( :ind, :xml)";
        my $sth =$dbh-> prepare($SQL);
        $sth->bind_param(":xml" , $xml , { ora_type => ORA_XMLTYPE});
        $sth->bind_param(":ind" , $i);
        $sth-> execute();


        $i++;
    }
}
```

Am getting the error in bind param.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error handling is usually done via the [`Try::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Try::Tiny) module:

```
use Try::Tiny;

try {
    something_that_could_die();
}
catch {
    handle_error($_);
}
finally {
    do_something_either_way();
}; # ← trailing semicolon not optional.
```

Both `catch` and `finally` are optional.